# How to Develop Ionic 2 Hybrid Mobile App with Navigation Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Angular 2 is released but Ionic 2 is still in beta, looking for some good examples of [Ionic 2 Hybrid Mobile App with Navigation Controller](http://www.icoderslab.com/develop-first-ionic-2-hybrid-mobile-app/), found this tutorial useful. is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you Josh's blog:
http://www.joshmorony.com/tag/ionic2/

And the link to his [navigation tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/a-simple-guide-to-navigation-in-ionic-2/)

Ionic just came out of beta and is in RC version now. It is based on angular 2 stable version and the build system was completely changed (from webpack/gulp to rollup).

Good luck with the tutorials!